# Downcasting gives ClassCastException. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, inheritance, downcast

I'm trying to implement a private message system. Let me know if this is bad design but I have two classes `User` and `Recipient`. `Recipient` is a `User` so it inherits `User`. `Recipient` has additional properties like `messageId`, `readDate`, `keepMessage`.

My code is as follows:

```
//This line gives me ClassCastException
recipient = (Recipient) user;
```

.

```
 //GET id of user to send message to
String receiverId = request.getParameter("id");

//GET title of message
String title = request.getParameter("title");

//Get content of message
String content = request.getParameter("content");

//Retrieve logged in user from session
HttpSession session = request.getSession();     
User sender = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

//Instantiate a new User to hold receiver
User user = new User();
//Retrieve object of user to send message to
UserService userService = new UserService();
user = userService.getUserById(Integer.valueOf(receiverId));

//Instantiate a new Recipient (extends User)
Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
//Cast User as a Recipient
recipient = (Recipient) user;

//Instantiate a message
Message message = new Message();
//message related stuff here....

//Pass the message content and Recipient to messageService
MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
messageService.sendPrivateMessage(message, recipient);
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile. You define the variable recipient twice

Comment: show user class syntax and Recipient class syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do that with Java. Based on what you said above you cannot cast a Recipient to a User. Do you really need to do this though? In the instance above it looks like you should be able to just instantiate it as a Recipient.

Comment: How is it possible to instantiate `userService.getUserById(Integer.valueOf(receiverId));` as a `Recipient` when it returns a `User`?

Comment: Are there different types of Users other than a Recipient? What I am thinking is that you could possibly make User an abstract class (or interface depending on what can be shared).

Comment: No there isn't. I'm wondering should I have a `Recipient` class at all? Instead of passing in a Recipient to `messageService.sendPrivateMessage(message, recipient);` should I just pass in `user.getUserId()`?

Comment: Or what about still passing in a `Recipient` but don't inherit from a `User` and just set the parameters? e.g. `recipient.setUserId(user.getUserId)` ?

Comment: If you instantiate the Object as a Recipient you should be fine, but I am not entirely sure that there needs to be a distinction between the two though.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your class hierarchy, which is another issue, you have multiple syntax problems. As I pointed out you are defining the recipient variable twice, with 2 different classes. Also, it looks like you are trying to cast a User to a Recipient, which will fail - a recipient is a user, but a user isn't necessarily a recipient

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a super class to a derived one. Where should the additional subclass data come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a cast.  Your best bet is to add a constructor to `Recipient` that takes a `User` argument.  Then you can do

```
Recipient recipient = new Recipient(user);
```

Either that or change `sendPrivateMessage()` to accept a `User` instead of a `Recipient`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good to do downcast, please check your class hierachy. if that object is really a child object, you can use dynamic_cast